# Make materilize css dropdown smaller in size

Tags: html, css, materialize

I need to make the drop down of the materialize css smaller in size.

The font the spacing and everything. I have trued with width: 50%; height: 50% but this doesnt reduce the size

Now: [image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <div class="col s12">

                <div class="col s6">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in single-opt" id="selectAll">
                    <label for="selectAll" id="selectAllLabel">Select all</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col s6">
                    <select id="select">
                        <option selected>Google Docs</option>
                        <option>Google Forms</option>
                        <option>Google Sheets</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('select').material_select();
                });
            </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
  <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col l4">
      <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in single-opt" id="selectAll">
      <label for="selectAll" id="selectAllLabel">Select all</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col l4" ">
                <select id="select ">
                    <option selected>Google Docs</option>
                    <option>Google Forms</option>
                    <option>Google Sheets</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('select').material_select();
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> try to refer grid layout of there..

Answer (score 1):

You can just scale it?

```
.select-wrapper {
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
```

You probably need to override the fixed width in the `ul` on smaller screens to make it wider.

```css
.select-wrapper {
  transform: scale(0.7);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <div class="col s12">

                <div class="col s6">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in single-opt" id="selectAll">
                    <label for="selectAll" id="selectAllLabel">Select all</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col s6">
                    <select id="select">
                        <option selected>Google Docs</option>
                        <option>Google Forms</option>
                        <option>Google Sheets</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('select').material_select();
                });
            </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the li and the nested a. These are the default applied styles:

```
// The <li>

.dropdown-content li {
    clear: both;
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
    cursor: pointer;
    min-height: 50px;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}

// The nested <a>

.dropdown-content li>a, .dropdown-content li>span {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #26a69a;
    display: block;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 14px 16px;
}
```

Something like this would be a quick reduction from 50px to 40px:

```
.dropdown-content li,
.dropdown-content li>a {  
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 0.9rem;
    min-height: unset;
}
```

As a final note - if you use [SASS](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/sass/components/_variables.scss#L159) in your projects, you can define the dropdown height (as well as the value of everything else in the framework) at the start of your project, rather than override it later down the line.

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/WNvZVMx)

Final final note!

The materialize select is a dropdown, in case you're wondering why I'm talking about dropdowns. Materialize hides the native select, replacing it with a text input that triggers a [dropdown](https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html). Both a dropdown and a select will be affected by the style declarations above.